# Unit Testing on Android with Firebase

Tags: android, unit-testing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my android application, I am using a Firebase real time database. I am writing the unit test cases for my application. Can we create another link for database in firebase for the same account, which we will use just for testing without touching the original database link ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to create a "Database Testing Link" on Firebase. But there are 2 actions you can take in order to run some tests without affecting your original database:

1. Export your database to JSON from the console (creating a backup point) and then run your tests. When you're done, you can re-import it (restoring from backup).
2. Create a second project with the same database structure and download the two google-services.json files (for both projects). Now when you want to run the tests, you paste in the google-services.json file from the second project. When you want to deploy the app or test it on a device, you replace the json file with the one from the first project.